# Backshifting with structure "make sure"

Tags: tense, backshifting

A similar problem has already been tackled at English Language & Usage, but it was not identical.

If I wanted to assure my SO, who is worried that we would not get adjacent seats on a plane, that I took care of everything, by asking my assistant do arrange it beforehand, would it be possible to say:

> Don't worry, dear, I made sure my assistant arranged everything, so that we will sit together.

Or would I be better off saying:

> Don't worry, dear, I made sure my assistant would arrange everything, so that we will sit together

As always, I'd really appreciate it if you could also correct my mistakes, should any appear.

Answer (score 1):

You could say

**I made sure my assistant had arranged everything**

That is, I checked before we departed that all of the arrangements had been made.

or

**I made sure my assistant arranged everything**

Same as above, often heard, but not quite as correct as the past perfect.

or

**I made sure my assistant would arrange everything**

That is, I confirmed before leaving that my assistant understood what I wished her to do.

P.S. On the sit/seated part of the question:

I would use simple present with a future meaning:

**... so that we *are* seated together.**

or

**...so that we can sit together.**

Comment: That "be" in my original post was superfluous, I accidentally left it while amending then previous version, in which I used a continuous form. Anyways, is using a future form here not acceptable? Any "sitting" hasn't yet occured and I'm assuring her about the future, so am I bound to using "would"?

Comment: I understand the first part just fine, and I'm well aware of the other possible forms. It's the "so that we will sit together" part that bugs me.

Comment: The case is a little more complex than I'd have thought, then. Searching "he made sure that we will" on Google leaves me with 354 000 positive results. Folks out there: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39976/backshifting-in-the-that-clause-of-make-sure also kind of aggree on using the "will" form. Are there any sinificant differences?

Comment: "so that we will be seated together" also works as does "for us to be seated together" as does "for us to sit together". There is more than one idiomatic way of expressing this idea.  Least viable, IMO, yet not impossible, is "so that we will sit together".

Answer (score 1):

The way you refer to your assistant arranging depends on whether he/she has already made the arrangements.  If he/she agreed to do it, but you're not sure if it is done, #2 is better. If you're sure it has been done, #1 is better.